# Data Stream encoding not supported yet (FFmpeg)

Tags: linux, audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a problem in my project, using FFmpeg. I am trying to use the `-map` option on the following way.

```
./ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf "scale=720x480" -map 0:p:59512 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 23 -c:a copy output.ts


Input #0, mpegts, from '/home/userlcv/Captures/input.ts':
      Duration: 00:00:31.54, start: 45748.050000, bitrate: 17061 kb/s
      Program 59488
        Metadata:
          service_name    : ?EPTV HD
          service_provider:
        Stream #0:0[0x111]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 28.58 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
        Stream #0:1[0x112]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
        Stream #0:2[0x113]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp
        Stream #0:3[0x116]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
        Stream #0:4[0x384]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
        Stream #0:5[0x1f4]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
        Stream #0:6[0x114]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
        Stream #0:7[0x115]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp
      Program 59512
        Metadata:
          service_name    : ?EPTV Mobile
          service_provider:
        Stream #0:8[0x211]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14.99 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
        Stream #0:9[0x212]: Audio: aac_latm (HE-AACv2) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
        Stream #0:10[0x216]: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
        Stream #0:11[0x38c]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)

 Stream #0:12[0x1fc]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
```

and get this error:

```
Data Stream encoding not supported yet (only streamcopy).
```

First, the `input.ts` is a recorded IDSBTb muxer output and the first hypothesis I have is the following: Is there a way to ignore some formats of the FFmpeg and work only with video and audio and recognize the option `-map 0:p:59512`.

When I deleted the option `-map 0:p:59512`, the system works fine and process the high resolution video but I need to filter another services because of `service_id` or `program_number`.

Comment: You should show the **complete** console output and not just segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can try

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf "scale=720x480" -map 0:p:59512 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 23 \
-c:a copy -c:d copy output.ts
```

If it complains about the 4th stream in that program, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf "scale=720x480" -map 0:p:59512 -map -i:0x38c -c:v libx264 \
-preset slow -crf 23 -c:a copy -c:d copy output.ts
```

Comment: Thanks Mulvya for the answer. But I am still having that problem. (Data stream encoding ...).I use -c copy and -copy_unknown , adding -map 0:p:59512 and works fine. I think is a problem of protocol format and a FFmpeg bug.

Comment: Not a bug, FFmpeg doesn't support, or even recognize, the codec of the data stream.

Comment: It only works with codecs it has been programmed for. Not all codecs are included. It's an open-source volunteer-driven project.